# Is there any justifiable reason to use new and a constructor on a number class in Java?

Tags: java, numbers, constructor

Is there any justifiable reason to in Java something like

```
Long l = new Long(SOME_CONSTANT)
```

This creates an extra object and is tagged by FindBugs, and is obviously a bad practice. My question is whether there is ever a good reason to do so?

I previously [asked this about String constructors and got a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390703/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-expression-new-string-in-java), but that answer doesn't seem to apply to numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only if you want to make sure you get a unique instance, so <sub>practically</sub> never.

Some numbers can be cached when autoboxed (although [`Longs` aren't guaranteed to be](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#190730)), which might cause problems. But any code that would break because of caching probably has deeper issues. Right now, I can't think of a single valid case for it.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is whether there is ever a good reason to do so?

You might still use it if you want to write code compatible with older JREs. [valueOf(long)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(long)) was only introduced in Java 1.5, so in [Java 1.4](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#Long(long)) and before the constructor was the only way to go directly from a *long* to a *Long*. I expect it isn't deprecated because the constructor is still used internally.

Comment: That is indeed a good reason (although, what percentage of Java apps are still on 1.4 or below?).

Comment: Old platforms can live for a long time, especially in the enterprise. When Java 6 came out, I was targeting a Java 1.3 platform.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. I was wondering why I was seeing it in legacy code.

Comment: Agree.  The default Java on our IBM platform is Java 1.4.    You will have to take my word for it that it can be very cumbersome to have a non-default Java installed, and that it is very often easier just to have your code 1.4 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is to make the boxing explicit, although the equivalent autoboxed code is actually compiled into Long.valueOf(SOME_CONSTANT) which can cache small values : (from jvm src)

```
   public static Long valueOf(long l) {
    final int offset = 128;
    if (l >= -128 && l <= 127) { // will cache
        return LongCache.cache[(int)l + offset];
    }
        return new Long(l);
  }
```

. Not a big deal, but I dislike seeing code that continually boxes and unboxes without regard for type, which can get sloppy.

Functionally, though, I can't see a difference one way or the other. The new long will still compute as equals and hashcode equals to the autoboxed one, so I can't see how you could even make a functional distinction if you wanted to.