# String created by constant expressions

Tags: java

Consider following code:

> ```
> String s = "Dear";
> String s1 = "My"+ s;  
> String s2 = "MyDear"; 
> String s3 = "My"+"Dear";
> ```

Here s1 and s3 are created by string constant expressions.

> System.out.println("    s2 == s3 is " + (s2 == s3));   //true

comes out to true because both s2 and s3 point to same interned String object but

> System.out.println("    s1 == s2 is " + (s1 == s2));   //false

comes out to fasle. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How "==" works for objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887626/how-works-for-objects)

Answer (score 4):

s1 is not created by a constant expression. s3 is.

Comment: Certainly this is the correct answer, with the [JLS definition of constant expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

Comment: OK! s1 is not created by constant expression. Am i right in saying that s1 is created during runtime and creates a `new String Object` whose reference is not same as `s2` so `s1==s2` comes out false?