# Why does appending "" to a String save memory?

Tags: java, performance, string, memory

I used a variable with a lot of data in it, say `String data`.
I wanted to use a small part of this string in the following way:

```
this.smallpart = data.substring(12,18);
```

After some hours of debugging (with a memory visualizer) I found out that the objects field `smallpart` remembered all the data from `data`, although it only contained the substring.

When I changed the code into:

```
this.smallpart = data.substring(12,18)+"";
```

..the problem was solved! Now my application uses very little memory now!

How is that possible? Can anyone explain this? I think this.smallpart kept referencing towards data, but why?

**UPDATE:**
How can I clear the big String then? Will data = new String(data.substring(0,100)) do the thing?

Comment: Reading more about your ultimate intent below: Where does the large string come from in the first place?  If read from a file or database CLOB or something then only reading what you need while parsing will be optimal all the way around.

Comment: Amazing...I am working in java more than 4 to 5 years, still this is new for me :). 

thanks for the info bro.

Comment: There is a subtlety to using `new String(String)`; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/390854/8946.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Doing the following:

```
data.substring(x, y) + ""
```

creates a new (smaller) String object, and throws away the reference to the String created by substring(), thus enabling garbage collection of this.

The important thing to realise is that `substring()` gives a window onto an *existing* String - or rather, the character array underlying the original String. Hence it will consume the same memory as the original String. This can be advantageous in some circumstances, but problematic if you want to get a substring and dispose of the original String (as you've found out).

Take a look at the [substring() method](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/lang/java/lang/String.java.htm) in the JDK String source for more info.

EDIT: To answer your supplementary question, constructing a new String from the substring will reduce your memory consumption, *provided* you bin any references to the original String.

NOTE (Jan 2013). The above behaviour has changed [in Java 7u6](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-May/010257.html). The flyweight pattern is no longer used and `substring()` will work as you would expect.

Comment: That's one of the very few cases where the `String(String)` constructor (i.e. the String constructor taking a String as input) is useful: `new String(data.substring(x, y))` does effectively the same thing as appending `""`, but it makes the intent somewhat clearer.

Comment: just to precise, substring uses the `value` attribute of the original string. I think that's why the reference is kept.

Comment: @Bishiboosh - yes, that's right. I didn't want to expose the particularities of the implementation, but that's precisely what's happening.

Comment: Technically it's an implementation detail. But it's frustrating nonetheless, and catches out a lot of people.

Comment: If I want to parse the big string step by step, how can I gradually decrease the memory use? please see my UPDATE!

Comment: @hsmit, you would have to copy the remainder substring to a new string also.  Note that by doing that you are copying large amounts of data repeatedly.  Your memory performance will improve at the cost of time performance.

Comment: This is one of the cases where C++ is easier.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to optimize this in the JDK using weak references or such.  If I'm the last person that needs this char [], and I only need a bit of it, make a new array for me to use internally.

Comment: How can I get a scenario to check it? I've tried some test but I got just opposite results

Comment: @NiveshSengar possibly because this is not true any longer since java 7 update 6.

Comment: There is a subtlety to using `new String(String)`; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/390854/8946.

Answer (score 28):

If you look at the source of `substring(int, int)`, you'll see that it returns:

```
new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
```

where `value` is the original `char[]`. So you get a new String but with the **same** underlying `char[]`.

When you do, `data.substring() + ""`, you get a new String with a **new** underlying `char[]`.

Actually, your use case is the only situation where you should use the `String(String)` constructor:

```
String tiny = new String(huge.substring(12,18));
```

Comment: There is a subtlety to using `new String(String)`; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/390854/8946.

Answer (score 17):

When you use `substring`, it doesn't actually create a new string. It still refers to your original string, with an offset and size constraint.

So, to allow your original string to be collected, you need to create a new string (using `new String`, or what you've got).

Answer (score 5):

In Java strings are imutable objects and once a string is created, it remains on memory until it's cleaned by the garbage colector (and this cleaning is not something you can take for granted).

When you call the substring method, Java does not create a trully new string, but just stores a range of characters inside the original string.

So, when you created a new string with this code:

```
this.smallpart = data.substring(12, 18) + "";
```

you actually created a new string when you concatenated the result with the empty string.
That's why.

Answer (score 5):

> I think this.smallpart kept
>   referencing towards data, but why?

Because Java strings consist of a char array, a start offset and a length (and a cached hashCode). Some String operations like `substring()` create a new String object that shares the original's char array and simply has different offset and/or length fields. This works because the char array of a String is never modified once it has been created.

This can save memory when many substrings refer to the same basic string without replicating overlapping parts. As you have noticed, in some situations, it can keep data that's not needed anymore from being garbage collected.

The "correct" way to fix this is the `new String(String)` constructor, i.e.

```
this.smallpart = new String(data.substring(12,18));
```

BTW, the overall best solution would be to avoid having very large Strings in the first place, and processing any input in smaller chunks, aa few KB at a time.

Comment: There is a subtlety to using `new String(String)`; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/390854/8946.

Answer (score 3):

As documented by [jwz in 1997](http://www.jwz.org/doc/java.html):

> If you have a huge string, pull out a substring() of it, hold on to the substring and allow the longer string to become garbage (in other words, the substring has a longer lifetime) the underlying bytes of the huge string never go away.

Answer (score 2):

Just to sum up, if you create lots of substrings from a small number of big strings, then use

```
   String subtring = string.substring(5,23)
```

Since you only use the space to store the big strings, but if you are extracting a just handful of small strings, from losts of big strings, then

```
   String substring = new String(string.substring(5,23));
```

Will keep your memory use down, since the big strings can be reclaimed when no longer needed.

That you call `new String` is a helpful reminder that you really are getting a new string, rather than a reference to the original one.

Comment: There is a subtlety to using `new String(String)`; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/390854/8946.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, **calling `java.lang.String.substring` creates new window on the original `String`** with usage of  the offset and length **instead of copying the significant part of underlying array.**

If we take a closer look at the `substring` method we will notice a *string constructor* call `String(int, int, char[])` and passing it whole `char[]` that represents the *string*. That means the *substring* will occupy as much amount of memory as the original *string*.

**Ok, but why `+ ""` results in demand for less memory than without it??**

Doing a `+` on `strings` is implemented via `StringBuilder.append` method call. Look at the implementation of this method in `AbstractStringBuilder` class will tell us that it finally do `arraycopy` with the part we just really need (the `substring`).

**Any other workaround??**

```
this.smallpart = new String(data.substring(12,18));
this.smallpart = data.substring(12,18).intern();
```

Answer (score 0):

Appending "" to a string will *sometimes* save memory.

Let's say I have a huge string containing a whole book, one million characters.

Then I create 20 strings containing the chapters of the book as substrings.

Then I create 1000 strings containing all paragraphs.

Then I create 10,000 strings containing all sentences.

Then I create 100,000 strings containing all the words.

I still only use 1,000,000 characters. If you add "" to each chapter, paragraph, sentence and word, you use 5,000,000 characters.

Of course it's entirely different if you only extract one single word from the whole book, and the whole book could be garbage collected but isn't because that one word holds a reference to it.

And it's again different if you have a one million character string and remove tabs and spaces at both ends, making say 10 calls to create a substring. The way Java works or worked avoids copying a million characters each time. There is compromise, and it's good if you know what the compromises are.