# vim accumulate number issue

Tags: vim

I want to have the following contents in my file

```
#define BIT_MASK_1      (1 << 0)
#define BIT_MASK_2      (1 << 1)
#define BIT_MASK_3      (1 << 2)
#define BIT_MASK_4      (1 << 3)
```

so I write one line like this :

```
#define BIT_MASK_1      (1 << 0)
```

, and then type `Y3p`, `V3j`, so I got four same lines which are selected, and after that I wanted to use the command below to turn the text into the content I want

```
:'<,'>s/BIT_MASK_/zs/d*/ze//=line(".") - line("'<") + 1
:'<,'>s//zs/d*/ze)$//=line(".")-line("'<")
```

but I got the `E488: Trailing characters` error, what did I do wrong?

Comment: I've tried to format this, but you have HTML tags mixed up in this. Please correct

Comment: have correct them, thanks for reminding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assume you have the 1st line: (cursor at beginning)

```
#define BIT_MASK_1      (1 << 0)
```

then you type : (`^A = Ctrl + A`)

```
qaYp^Af<^Aq
```

then

```
3@a
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't help thinking you're better off using Ctrl+A ([increments the number under the cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147783/why-does-appending-to-a-string-save-memory/2147803#2147803)) and an interactively defined [macro](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/vi-and-vim-macro-tutorial-how-to-record-and-play/) to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but I'd rather use C-a to increment the numbers

Something like

```
t(h^At)^A0
```

you can put it in a macro and run it as many times as needed

Comment: It's because the formatting has changed, spaces have been added.

Answer (score 0):

Just type this:

```
:for i in range( 1, 4 ) | call append( line( '$' ), [ '#define BITMASK_' . i . ' (1 << ' . (i - 1) . ')' ] ) | endfor
```

Sometimes the using of vim as a programing language is better then using weird keystrokes.