# I have a string variable and another string assigned to same variable. Then how to get old string?

Tags: java, string

Suppose I have a string

```
msg = "hello"
```

Now I get substring from string `msg` like `msg.substring(1,msg.length())`

And storing that substring into `msg`.

So `msg` refers to new string. If the old string also remain in buffer of java and yes then how to access it?

Comment: Wow, why would you want to do that? Simply use another variable that you assign msg to?

Comment: Ur right.. but I just want to know... What happen to that old string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there are no longer any references to a memory block (a Java object, which is your String msg), that memory can be reclaimed (collected). Which means old, unused object is automaticaly removed by the garbage collector, so there is no any easy way to do it.. More info about garbage collection [here](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/background/60garbage_collection.html).

**UPDATE.** As it is mentioned by Brian Agnew in comments, this answer is correct for Java versions 7u6 and higher.

Comment: This is not completely correct. substring may return a string object which refers to the original String with an offset.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind - depending on the version of Java in use. See my answer for more details

Answer (score 8):

Note that `String.substring()` implementation and the actual implementation of `String` has changed with Java 7 (release 6, IIRC)

So depending on your Java version:

1. if it's post Java 7u6, you can't do this. `String.substring()` will give you a completely new string
2. if it's an older version of Java, you *could* access the private underlying char array of your new `String`, and this is in fact the *complete* char array of your old string

Item 2 is particularly nasty, and I suspect beyond what you really want to achieve.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147783/why-does-appending-to-a-string-save-memory/2147803#2147803) for more details behind the substring() implementation and how it's changed.