# new String() in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of the expression “new String(…)” in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390703/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-expression-new-string-in-java)

I've found some old code that has new String("somestring") in it. Has there ever been a time when this was a good idea?

Comment: Multiple duplicates, including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390703/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-expression-new-string-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but only for some usually rare case, like when you really have to make sure, that two Strings with equal content are **not** the same.

For details and other reasons - please refer to the numerous brilliant answers to the numerous questions concerning `new String("something")`.

Comment: That's definitely not the only case. See other questions' answers for details.

Comment: @Michael - fully agreed. applied a small edit to reflect this comment.