# what is the advantage of string object as compared to string literal

Tags: java

i want to know where to use string object(in which scenario in my java code). 
ok i understood the diff btwn string literal and string object, but i want to know that since java has given us the power to make string object, there must be some reason, at some point string object creation would be useful. so i want to know in which scenario can we prefer string object in place of string literal.

Comment: A string literal is a string object.

Comment: At some point, that's more or less the same as asking why you should use `int` variables instead of numeric constants.

Comment: And that's not that trivial a question (`int` vs. constants). Leads to magic numbers vs. "not a global parameter, just need it this once..." etc.

Comment: Yeah, I think I remember seeing a language, or a compiler supposedly implementing a global dictionary of numeric constants. After something like `const int a = 1; *(int*)&a = 2;`, 1 becoming 2 **everywhere**...

Comment: Can you be more specific? It looks like most answers concentrate on `String s = new String("xx")`. Is it what you were talking about?

Answer (score 6):

In most situations, you should use String literals to avoid creating unnecessary objects.  This is actually **Item 5: Avoid creating unnecessary objects** of Effective Java:

> #### Item 5: Avoid creating unnecessary objects
>
> It is often appropriate to reuse a
>   single object instead of creating a
>   new functionally equivalent object
>   each time it is needed. Reuse can be
>   both faster and more stylish. An
>   object can always be reused if it is
>   immutable (Item 15). As an extreme
>   example of what not to do, consider
>   this statement:
>
> ```
> String s = new String("stringette"); // DON'T DO THIS!
> ```
>
> The statement creates a new `String`
>   instance each time it is executed, and
>   none of those object creations is
>   necessary. The argument to the String
>   constructor (`"stringette"`) is itself a
>   String instance, functionally
>   identical to all of the objects
>   created by the constructor. If this
>   usage occurs in a loop or in a
>   frequently invoked method, millions of
>   String instances can be created
>   needlessly. The improved version is
>   simply the following:
>
> ```
> String s = "stringette";
> ```
>
> This version uses a single `String`
>   instance, rather than creating a new
>   one each time it is executed.
>   Furthermore, it is guaranteed that the
>   object will be reused by any other
>   code running in the same virtual
>   machine that happens to con- tain the
>   same string literal [JLS, 3.10.5]

There is however one situation where you want to use the `new String(String)` constructor: when you want to force a substring to copy to a new underlying character array like in:

```
String tiny = new String(huge.substring(0, 10));
```

This will allow the big underlying `char[]` from the original `huge` String to be recycled by the GC.

Comment: Could you explain why String `tiny = new String(huge.substring(0, 10));` is eligible for GC? On the other hand why `tiny = huge.substring(0, 10);` not eligible?

Comment: @Sujee With `tiny = huge.substring(0, 10)`, `tiny` would use the **same** `char[]` than `huge`. With `String tiny = new String(huge.substring(0, 10))`, `tiny` would use a new (smaller) `char[]`, allowing the big one to be recycled. Check the sources for the details.

Comment: There is a subtlety to using `new String(String)`; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/390854/8946.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a *new* `String` object if you know what the string is. For example:

```
String str = new String("foo"); // don't do this
```

You are thus creating an unnecessary object - once you have a `String` object created from the literal, and then you create another one, taking the first one as constructor argument.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to your question, there is a DISADVANTAGE of using a String object compared to String literal.

When you declare a String literal, `String s = "foo"`, the compiler will check for an existing "foo" object on the heap and assign 's' to already existing "foo".

However, if you create a String object, `String s = new String("foo")`, an entirely new object will be created on the heap (even if there is already an existing "foo"). Strings being immutable this is totally unnecessary.

Here is good reference: http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/ScjpTipLine-StringsLiterally.html

Answer (score 2):

```
String a = "ABC";
String b = new String("ABC");
String c = "ABC";

a == b // false
a == c // true

a.equals(b) // true
a.equals(c) // true
```

The point is that a & c point to the same "ABC" object (JVM magic). Using "new String" creates a new object each time. IMO, using string object is a disadvantage, not an advantage. However, as another poster said, string object is useful for converting byte[], char[], StringBuffer - if you need to do that.

Answer (score 2):

String literals are converted to String objects, and as others pointed out, creating explicit String objects is unnecessary and inperformant, as it defeats [String pooling](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3).

However, there is one situation where you want to create new Strings explicitly: If you use just a small part of a very long String. `String.substring()` prevents the original String from getting GC'd, so you can save memory when you write

```
String s = new String(veryLongString.substring(1,3));
```

instead of

```
String s = veryLongString.substring(1,3);
```

Comment: There is a subtlety to using `new String(String)`; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/390854/8946.

Answer (score 0):

literal strings are objects created in a String Pool and if they have the same value, they are referencing to the same object.

```
System.out.println("abc"=="abc"); // the output is true
```

Meanwhile, string object are real objects in memory and if they have the same value, there's no guarantee that they are referencing to the same object.

```
String a = new String("abc");
String b = new String("abc");
System.out.println(a==b); // the output is false
```