# scanner.nextLine() doesn't actually give the next line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've written a pretty simple recursive-descent parser in Java, but having some issues with the scanner I've attached to the file.

```
private void ParseDataFields(Controller.TreeData data, java.util.Scanner scanner) {
        java.lang.String nextline;
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            nextline = scanner.nextLine().trim();
            if (nextline == "{") { // If we are with this, we are a new Child object declaration.
                if (data.CanHaveChildren()) {
                    ParseDataFields(data.CreateNewChild(), scanner);
                    continue;
                } else
                    FileValidationError("Attempted to give a child object to a data node that could not have one.");
            }
            if (nextline.endsWith("}")) // End of Child object data declaration
                return;
            ... parse the line
```

The problem is that when { is found, the method recurses, but the next line isn't actually taken (there is a next line). It just gives back the same { token, which is not valid.

I've been using a sample file to test this out:

```
Name = scumbag
{
    Name = lolcakes
}
}
```

Used reflection and I confirmed that the field=value syntax is working fine. But the opening token for a new child isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (nextline == "{") {
```

Comparing strings in Java should be done with [`String#equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
if (nextline.equals("{")) {
```

Strings are objects in Java, not primitives. The `==` would compare objects by reference, not by value.

#### See also:

- [Java == for String objects ceased to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370184/java-for-string-objects-ceased-to-work)
- [difference between string object and string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297867/difference-between-string-object-and-string-literal)

Comment: I thought that strings were interned and thus any two Strings with the same value will have the same reference.

Comment: That's only true for Strings that are the result of constant expressions, for example, literals in your code. See the Java language spec, 3rd edition, 3.10.5.

Comment: @DeadMG: the following is true: `"{" == "{"`, but `"{" == new String("{")` definitely not. That's what is happening here.

Comment: It didn't occur to me that the condition failing when it shouldn't would also produce the problem that I had. Thanks for this correct answer.