# What's the difference between String and new String?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of the expression “new String(…)” in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390703/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-expression-new-string-in-java)

What's the difference between these two statements:

```
String a1 = new String("abc");
```

and

```
String a2 = "abc";
```

If you could illustrate the difference, that would be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390703/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-expression-new-string-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is creating a new String object; the second one is effectively using one which already exists (it's created while loading the class file.) There is virtually never a reason to use the `String(String)` constructor.

(I say *virtually* because there is one case: if you're breaking up a huge `String` by calling `substring()` and then discarding the original, you can save memory by using this constructor to create new `String`s from the sub-strings. That's really an obscure case, though.)

Comment: Unless you wanted two `String`s which are `.equal` but not `==`.