# Suppose str is a String variable. The statement str = new String("Hello World"); is equivalent to?

Tags: java

Java Question:  Suppose str is a String variable. The statement                               str = new String("Hello  World");   is equivalent to ?

Here are my choices...

a.

```
new String = "Hello World";
```

c.

```
str = "Hello World";
```

b.

```
String new = "Hello World";
```

d.

```
"Hello World";
```

Comment: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191086/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-new-string) -  [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952581/what-is-the-difference-between-strings-allocated-using-new-operator-without-ne)

Comment: Is equivalent to create pottentionally 2 strings.. "Hello World" if  it doesn't exist in the "pool" and a new allocation with the same value.

Comment: @nachokk The literal *does* exist in the pool: it is put there by the compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's equivalent to declaring and initializing it at once:

```
String str = new String("Hello World");
```

You don't need to do `new String("...")` though. You already have a String literal. You can just do:

```
String str = "Hello World";
```

Otherwise, you're taking the first, canonical String object (`"Hello World"`) and unnecessarily using it to initialize a second object (`new String(...)`) with the same text.

Edit: According to the choices you've posted now, it's not *exactly* equivalent to *any* of them. As explained in more detail by the other answers, `"Hello World"` has a subtle (yet important) difference to `new String("Hello World")`, so it is not exactly equivalent to `str = "Hello World"`. On the other hand, the other three options don't compile at all, so that is certainly the intended answer.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of answer get it right about internalization. Take this program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "Hello";
    String str2 = "Hello";
    String str3 = new String("Hello");
    String str4 = "He";
    System.out.println(str1 == str2);  // true

    System.out.println(str1 == str3);  // false

    System.out.println(str1 == str3.intern());  // true

    str4 = str4.concat("llo");
    System.out.println(str1 == str4.intern());  // true

}
```

The interesting issues are point 2 and 3. `new` always creates a new object (as per JLS 12.5), so `str1 != str3`. What happens with internalization is that the new object points to the internalized one, which you can retrieve with `String.intern()`. Similarly, another `String` created in a form completely unrelated to the original literals (`str4`) also gets "interned".

Comment: Even more answers got it wrong, for some reason :-|