# substrings and garbage in java 1.6

Tags: java

Using a profiler, I seem to be seeing the following with Apple's 1.6 Java:

I start with a moderately long Java string. I split it into tokens using `String.split("\\W+")`. The code then holds references to some of the split up pieces.

It seems, if I believe my eyes in yourkit, that Java has helpfully *not* copied these strings, so that I'm in fact holding references to the lengthy originals. In my case this leads to a rather large waste of space.

Does this seem plausible? It's easy enough to add a loop making copies of these guys.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct. See Jon Skeet's comment on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/07/19/strings-immutability-and-persistence.aspx

Comment: String.substring does the same

Comment: Related: [What is the purpose of the expression "new String(…)" in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390703)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.split()` does not copy the parts of the `String` [the new objects...], instead it uses the `String`'s fields: `offset` and `count`. By "changing" them, when later you access the `String` object, it is done by adding the offset to the original reference. This is indeed done to prevent copying the whole `String`, and save space [well, at least usually...].

So basically yes. All of your new objects, will have the same `char[]` reference, which leads to the original `char[]`, in the original `String`.