# Java :Connection between stringpool object and heap object when new String() is used

Tags: java, string, immutability

I know in case of new String("Hi") it will create two objects one in heap and other in stringpool . I am curious about do these two objects share any linkage if yes then how ?

Comment: No, there's no link between them other than that they have the same contents.  That said, there's essentially never any good reason to write that code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390703/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-expression-new-string-in-java

Answer (score 0):

new String("hi"). It will store Hi in the string constant pool and the reference is passed to the String variable referring this object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String string=new String("Hi");     
}
Traces for the above program.
```

TraceEntry

```
Entry : programIt/stringval.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V Bytecode static method

Entry : java/lang/String.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V Bytecode method, This = 0xfffb93c0

Entry : java/lang/Object.<init>()V Compiled method, This = 0xfffb93c0

Exit : java/lang/Object.<init>()V Compiled method

Exit : java/lang/String.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V Bytecode method

Exit : programIt/stringval.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V Bytecode static method
```

---

It has only one string Entry and Exit which  obviously means it has one reference present. if 2 reference exist then there  will be
2 internal String calls present for 2 references.

Comment: But I think there will be one object in heap which has value as "hi"  and other string literal object in string pool ...Correct me if I am wrong ... can you share that source code snippet where this reference passing is done?

Comment: Edited above with more clarifications