# String foo = "bar" vs. String foo = new String ("bar") in Android?

Tags: java, variables

I did search on this but the keywords must be too generic to narrow down the relevant bits. Why are both ways of declaring a string valid in android and is there any difference?

Comment: They are the same.  I would recommend checking out this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.htmlYou are basically instantiating a new instance of the String object.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so I suspect that there is no difference.  You could examine the bytecode generated by each to see if there is any difference.

Comment: Probably should be closed as copy of [String vs new String()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for the links, and apologies for duplicating the question. I spent a good 10 minutes trying to find a similar Q before posting but there were way too many results to scroll through and many were c++ and ios related. This is what I wanted: "You very rarely would ever want to use the new String(anotherString) constructor. From the API..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is java syntax and not only specific to Android. Here is a discussion on this. [String vs new String()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

Using the `new` keyword you create a new string object, where using `foo = "bar"` will be optimized, to point to the same string object which is used in a different place in your app.

For instacne:

```
String foo = "bar";
String foo2 = "bar";
```

the compiler will optimize the above code to be the same exact object [`foo == foo2`, in conradiction to `foo.equals(foo2)`].

**EDIT:** after some search, @Sulthan was right. It is not compiler depended issue, it is in the [specs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#100960):

> A string literal always refers to the same instance (§4.3.1) of class
>   String.

Comment: This is not decided by compiler. The behavior is strictly defined.

Comment: @Sulthan: Can you provide some reference to that statement? I failed to see it in the specs, but will gladly modify my answer if such can be provided.

Comment: Docs for `String.intern()`. `All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned`

Comment: @Sulthan: You were right, I found it in the specs. edited my answer. thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is not only about Android, it's about Java.

When you write `"xxxx"` it is a literal string. It's a String instance. Note, that all literal strings with the same value are the same instance. See method `String.intern()` for details.

Example:

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "abc";
```

in this example, `s1 == s2` is true.

`new String("xxx")` is a copy constructor. You take one string (the literal) and you create a new instance from it. Since all strings are immutable, this is usually something you don't want to do.

Example:

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = new String("abc");
```

`s1.equals(s2)` is true
`s1 == s2` is false

Answer (score 0):

```
String x = new String( "x" )
```

effectively creates 2 Strings. One for the literal (which is a expression with no variable name) and one that you keep as x then. It is the same as:

```
String x;
{
  String a = "x";
  x = new String( a );
}
```