# Object Creation JAVA

Tags: java, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between “text” and new String(“text”) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext-in-java)

Please explain the brief and detailed difference between following 2 statements:

```
String a= "somevalue";
String b = new String("somevalue");
```

I know that 2nd statement creates and provide memory to String Object `b` in heap. But why object `a` doesn't get memory and its still allowed to operate on string methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` and `b` are references to Objects, not Objects.

When you do `a = b;` it doesn't copy the Object, it copies a reference to an Object.

A String has a `char[]` inside it which is another object.

`a` gets an reference to an existing object so it may not need any extra memory.

`b` get a reference to a newly created object so that requires more memory.

> its still allowed to operate on string methods.

This has nothing to do with how the object was created.

Comment: thank you @Peter. i want to add something. You should use `a` if you know object before creating, but use `b` in opposite case.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry: b should NEVER be used. It makes no sense to create a copy of an immutable object. It only wastes memory and CPU cycles.

Comment: @JBNizet Unless the `char[]` which backs the String is excessive in which case you need to take a copy of the bit you want. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The first affects the literal String object "somvalue" to variable `a`. This literal String object is cached in a pool, as all literal Strings.

The second creates a new instance of empty String. Since String instances are immutable, it's equivalent to `String b = "";`, except it instantiates a new object for nothing.