# Java Method Call Expected

Tags: java

This is a java program with two buttons used to change an integer value and display it.
However in IntelliJIDEA the two lines with

```
increase.addActionListener(incListener());
decrease.addActionListener(decListener());
```

keep displaying errors 'Method call expected'.

I am not sure what to do to fix this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Note: the full code is attached below.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends JDialog {
public JPanel contentPane;
public JButton decrease;
public JButton increase;
public JLabel label;

public int number;

public Main() {
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    setModal(true);

    increase = new JButton();
    decrease = new JButton();
    increase.addActionListener(incListener());
    decrease.addActionListener(decListener());

    number = 50;
    label = new JLabel();
}

public class incListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        number++;
        label.setText("" + number);
    }
}

public class decListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        number--;
        label.setText("" + number);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main dialog = new Main();
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    System.exit(0);

}
}
```

Comment: Instead of `incListener()` and `decListener()` make them `new incListener()` and `new decListener()`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

incListener and declListener are classes, not methods.

Try

```
increase.addActionListener(new incListener());
```

btw, rename your classes names to make them start with an uppercase

Answer (score 6):

It's simple: use `new incListener()` instead of `incListener()`. The later is trying to *call a method* named `incListener`, the former *creates an object* from the class `incListener`, which is what we want.

Answer (score 1):

incListener and decListener are a classes but not a methods, so you must call new to use them, try this:

increase.addActionListener(new incListener());
decrease.addActionListener(new decListener());

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

substitute the lines with

```
increase.addActionListener( new incListener());
decrease.addActionListener( new decListener());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes:

```
 public Main() {
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    setModal(true);

    increase = new JButton("inc");
    decrease = new JButton("dec");
    contentPane.add(increase);
    contentPane.add(decrease);
    increase.addActionListener(new incListener());
    decrease.addActionListener(new decListener());

    number = 50;
    label = new JLabel(number+"");
    contentPane.add(label);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's sad but I had to Google this same error... I was staring at a method that returned a class. I left off the `new` operator.

`return <class>(<parameters>)`
vs
`return new <class>(<parameters>)`

Answer (score -1):

Whenever a string object is created using **new** operator a new object is created which is what your program is looking for. 
The following link is useful in learning about the difference between a string and a new string.
[What is the difference between "text" and new String("text")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext)