# Android: method call expected error

Tags: java, android, arrays, methods

I've searched internet for that error and have not found right answer. I've got error saying "method call expected" on `mPrefsKeys` in `bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(mPrefsKeys(i)))`

```
public final static String [] mPrefsKeys = new String[]{"username", "devicename"}
bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(mPrefsKeys(i)))

public Preference findPreference(CharSequence key) {
    if (mPreferenceManager == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return mPreferenceManager.findPreference(key);
}
```

What that error means?

Answer (score 2):

I spent significant effort to search for the answer what that error means.

Then somehow reading something ([Java Method Call Expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418193/java-method-call-expected)) I was enlighted: array items should be referenced with [], not ().

Comment: anyone knows why the error is worded that way? why method expected whereas CharSequence is a parameter in findPreference?