# How many objects are created in this

Tags: java, oop

In this class how many objects will be created of the string?

```
public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = new String("abc");
        String s = "def";
        s = s + "fgh";
    }
}
```

Comment: 5 string objects will be created.

Comment: what is this question good for?

Comment: Have a look [String constant pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext-in-java/23546082#23546082)

Comment: 3 in constant pool "abc", "def" and "fgh" and 1 is in heap `string` itself and 1 is `s + "fgh"`. Total 5 objects are created.

Comment: If there are so many different opinions, that cant be a bad question at all :D

Comment: How to check how many objects are created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about how many *String* objects are created, then the answer is 5 String objects.

```
String string = new String("abc"); // 2 Strings with value "abc" , one on heao and another in String constants pool
String s = "def"; // String "def" on String constants pool
s = s + "fgh"; // String "deffgh" on heap and "fgh" on String pool
```

Many objects are created internally, like `StringBuilder`, `arrays` etc you should not consider those now.