# How to create string object in java

Tags: java

`String s="abc"` in java.what happened in the memory any object is created or not and what is "`s`" here variable or object,and same question with `String s=new String("abc");`.

Comment: Only two lines and horrible to read. Use punctuation. Also, flagged as duplicate. Use google. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext-in-java

Answer (score 2):

There's a thing called String Memory Pool in java, when you declare:

```
String str1="abc";
```

It goes to that memory pool and not on the heap. But when you write:

```
String str2=new String("abc");
```

It creates a full fledged object on the heap, If you again write:

```
String str3 = "abc";
```

It won't create any more object on the pool, it will check the pool if this literal already exists it will assign that to it. But writing:

```
String str4 = new String("abc");
```

will again create a new object on the heap

Key point is that:

A new object will always be created on the heap as many times as you keep writing:

```
new String("abc");
```

But if you keep assigning the Strings directly without using the keyword new, it will just get referenced from the pool (if it exists in the pool)

Answer (score 0):

The String class represents character strings. All string literals in Java programs, such as "abc", are implemented as instances of this class.

[String Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: You are correct, however part of OP asked " what is "s" here variable or object,and same question with String s=new String("abc") :)

Comment: It's is an object but we call it as a String literal just because the object does not lies on the heap, java created the concept of string memory pool because strings are heavily used, and it's not a good thing to create a new object containing same data everytime