# Token iterator class to decompile math expressions not working with numbers

Tags: java, iterator, token

I have a class where I have to print each token of a math expression. I have got my code to the point where it prints out everything except the numbers together. I am not sure what to fix in order to do that.

This is what the desired output is:

```
next token: [15] 

next token: [*] 

next token: [(] 

next token: [26]
```

And this is what my code currently produces:

```
next token: [1] 

next token: [5] 

next token: [*] 

next token: [(] 

next token: [2]
```

etc...

Here is my code:

```
public class TokenIter implements Iterator<String> {
    static int counter = 0;
    private String line;
    private String nextToken;

    public TokenIter(String line) {
        this.line = line;
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "  15*(26+37) - 443/7*612 - (233-543234)   ";
        System.out.println("line: [" + line + "]");
        TokenIter tokIt = new TokenIter(line);
        // print tokens in square brackets to check absence of white space
        while (tokIt.hasNext()) {
            if (tokIt.next() != "no")
                System.out.println("next token: [" + tokIt.next() + "]");
            counter++;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (counter < line.length())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public String next() {
        String s = "";
        if (!hasNext())
            return null;
        else {
            char c = line.charAt(counter);
            if (c == ('/')) {
                counter = counter++;
                s = "" + c;
                return s;
            }
            if (c == ('+')) {
                counter = counter++;
                s = "" + c;
                return s;
            }
            if (c == ('*')) {
                counter = counter++;
                s = "" + c;
                return s;
            }
            if (c == ('-')) {
                counter = counter++;
                s = "" + c;
                return s;
            }
            if (c == ('(')) {
                counter = counter++;
                s = "" + c;
                return s;
            }
            if (c == (')')) {
                counter = counter++;
                s = "" + c;
                return s;
            } else if (c == ' ') {
                counter = counter++;
                return "no";
            }
            while (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                counter = counter++;
                s += "" + c;
                return s;
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

I understand there are other ways to do this like a string tokenizer with delimiters, but I need to do it this way.

Comment: @ali_m Yes...I just need help on how to fix my code so that the numbers are together. Help would be nice, please.

Comment: Before I dig deeper into your program: `if (tokIt.next() != "no")` is wrong. Please read this: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832).

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code contains several issues:

- `if (tokIt.next() != "no")`

  This is not the proper way to compare Strings. Use `#equals` instead: `if (!tokIt.next().equals("no"))`. Your current correctly compares your strings an can find `"no"`, because you used a [String literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext). This wouldn't work if for example a user enters *"no"* into the console and you try to compare it using `!= "no"`. So keep that in mind
- You're calling `tokIt.next()` two times. The first time is in the if statement I've mentioned above and the second time is in `System.out.println("next token: [" + tokIt.next() + "]");`. If your code would move the cursor correctly (by increasing `counter`), then you would skip every second token. Create a new String to carry the token `String token = tokIt.next();` and use it to compare it with *"no"* and to print it.
- You shouldn't call `counter++;` in your `main` method. This will move the cursor to the next character in the String. Leave that to the `next` method. Only this method should move the cursor.
- Not an issue, but your `hasNext` can be simplified to:

  ```
  public boolean hasNext() {
      return counter < line.length();
  }
  ```
- Don't use `counter = counter++;`. `counter++` is the same as:

  ```
  int temp = counter;
  counter = counter + 1;
  return temp;
  ```

  So if you write `counter = counter++;` you're setting `counter` to its old value, after adding 1 to it. That means, `counter` wouldn't change its value. You could remove the `counter =` part, but ...
- Don't call `counter++` in every `if` branch in your `next` method. Do it once in `char c = line.charAt(counter);`:

  ```
  char c = line.charAt(counter++);
  ```

  That way you read the value at the current `counter` and increase its value, so the next time you read something, it will be the next position.
- Don't create the variable `s`: This is not an issue, but it isn't helpful either. Since every `if` branch contains something like

  ```
  if (c == (...)) {
      s = "" + c;
      return s;
  }
  ```

  you can write instead:

  ```
  if (c == (...)) {
      return Character.toString(c);
  }
  ```

  This also avoid the "awkward" version of Character conversion to String: `"" + c`.
- Don't use these many `if` statements to do a simple check and then return the same character. You can do something like this instead:

  ```
  if ("/+*-()".indexOf(c) >= 0) {
      return Character.toString(c);
  }
  ```

  That way, you can check all allowed mathematical characters in one `if` statement. And it is "nicer" to add new characters.
- This is your current `while` loop which should read every combined digit:

  ```
  while (Character.isDigit(c)) {
      counter = counter++;
      s += "" + c;
      return s;
  }
  ```

  As you can see, it will return `s` on the first `while` loop iteration. What you really need is to remove that return and to read the next character from the source string to add it to `s`. This can look like this:

  ```
  String s = ""; // since we removed the old "s" (see my seventh remark), we need to create it here
  while (Character.isDigit(c)) {
      s += Character.toString(c); // add current character to String s
      c = line.charAt(counter++); // read next character
      if (!Character.isDigit(c)) { // if it is not a digit
          counter--; // move the cursor one position back
          break; // stop the loop
      }
  }
  ```

After you've followed my remarks, your output should then be:

```
line: [  15*(26+37) - 443/7*612 - (233-543234)   ]
next token: [15]
next token: [*]
next token: [(]
next token: [26]
next token: [+]
next token: [37]
next token: [)]
next token: [-]
next token: [443]
next token: [/]
next token: [7]
next token: [*]
next token: [612]
next token: [-]
next token: [(]
next token: [233]
next token: [-]
next token: [543234]
next token: [)]
```

I know, there are better ways to achieve OPs goal, but I think he still should use his own approach and learn from it.