# String created as literal and new operator

Tags: string, new-operator, literals, pool

When I declare a String using:

```
String a = new String("Hello");
```

2 objects are created. 1 object resides in heap and  another in String literal pool.

So when I do:

```
String b = "Hello";
```

Is a new object created or is `"Hello"` from String pool referenced to `b`?

Comment: Does this not depend on the language used?

Comment: @SDC, is it Java? If yes, please tag it so.

Answer (score 0):

A new object is created.

### Explanation

- `new String("Hello")` creates one object *on the heap*. It is not stored in the String literal pool. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext).
- `String b = "Hello"` first wants to reuse String `"Hello"` from the pool, but there is none. So, it will create a new `"Hello"` String object *in the pool* and assign your reference to it.

You can read more about String literals in [Java Language Specification 3.10.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5).

### Test

We can [test](http://ideone.com/MVUxM2) that the references are pointing to different objects:

```
String a = new String("Hello");
String b = "Hello";
System.out.println(a == b);
```

Prints `false`, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am talking about Java language. I have read in many places that

```
String a = new String("Hello")
```

creates 2 objects. One is in Heap. Could you please let me know where is the other object created?