# System.out.println((a+c)==(b+d)); why this statement returning false?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

    public class StringTest{
        public static void main(String[] args){

            String a="Hello";
            String b="Hello";

            String c=new String("Hello");
            String d=new String("Hello");

            System.out.println(a+c);  
            System.out.println(b+d);  
            System.out.println((a+c)==(b+d));
        }
    }
```

Why this `System.out.println((a+c)==(b+d));`  statement returning `false`?

Answer (score 1):

Because String is a class, and because of that, the `==` operator checks for reference equality. Use the `equals(Object)` method instead. (that is: `(a + c).equals(b + d);`)

Comment: There are so many answers in `stackOverFlow` regarding this question.

Comment: if i compare a==c then the '=='  checks for the reference and it will return true so the same thing should happen for this ((a+c)==(b+d)) statement also right?

Comment: @M.Kishore no, the only comparison that returns true should be `a==b`, because these objects will be pointing to the same String instance (they are both String literals). The `new String("Hello")` will force that the String will be created as a new Object. [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext)

Comment: Yes.  It would print `true` if the references were equal.  But they aren't, so it doesn't.  The two string concatenations produce different objects.  They are "equal" ... but not the same object.