# Empty constructor in String class

Tags: java, string, constructor, char, string-pool

So I was reading String class when i stumbled on one confusing constructor. The code goes like this

```
public final class String
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence {

    /** The value is used for character storage. */
    private final char value[];

    /** Initializes a newly created {@code String} object so that it represents
    * an empty character sequence.  Note that use of this constructor is
    * unnecessary since Strings are immutable.
    */
    public String() {
        this.value = "".value;
    }
// the rest of the class code
}
```

I don't understand what does

> `"".value;`

do. What is this `""`? Is it a new `String object`? If it is, with what constructor?

Comment: this means string with 0 length

Comment: this is simple String literal object resides on String pool..  see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext

Comment: Can you provide a link to the code in question? Because OpenJDK [7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l151) and [8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l138) have `this.value = new char[0];`.

Comment: @dhke I unpacked src.zip from jdk1.8.0_71
[https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1ab847ab5a108637cd7bbcf82026a6cf#file-string-java-L138](gist line 138)

Comment: @ThrashAbaddon It's also in JDK9. See my answer, below and also for possible rationale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is this ""? Is it a new String object?

It's an empty string. It does not have to be *new* and most likely isn't, since string literals are [interned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

> If it is, with what constructor?

At compile time the empty string was probably created by the source code [`Scanner`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/tools/java/Scanner.java) from a [sequence of input characters](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/tools/java/Scanner.java#l157) using [`String(char[], int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-char:A-int-int-).

At runtime, the `ClassLoader` has loaded and interned the String from the class file in native code probably via [`java_lang_String::create_from_unicode()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/classfile/javaClasses.cpp#l185) and friends.

As for why using `""`: It is a memory use optimization. Since string literals are [interned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), `"".value` is a reference to the same underlying char array for every empty string.

From the repositories, OpenJDK ([7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l151), [8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l138)) previously used `this.value = new char[0];`. A new char array object was created for every `new String()` appearing in source code (i.e. hopefully never).

Current OpenJDK 9 has [`"".value`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/file/7ea7d502b4b5/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l218).

The change prevents creating a new char array and thus saves a few bytes per non-interned, but newly created empty string. After the change, all zero-length strings share the same (zero-length) char array.

I'd consider this a rare case, because I cannot recall if I ever used `new String()` anywhere.

Comment: I really shouldn't write comments at 3 a.m., *mea culpa,* but there still isn't any such thing as '*the*' Java compiler. Describing what one implementation does can't possibly answer the question properly.

Comment: @EJP You are right there, of course, that where the *probably* comes in, which should be read as a short form of *If using the standard JDK compiler, then ...*. But the answer can also do without the breadcrumb trail of where the string comes from in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`""` is a `String` and thus has a `char[] values` as any `String` would. However, it has no characters, making `values` an empty array.

Basically, the code initializes `values` to an empty array.