# How String object is created from an literal?

Tags: java, string

I understand the interning and StringPool concepts. But I fail to understand how a String literal is converted to String object.
For e.g.

`String abc = "abc";`

The above line will create an String object. How does this shortcut work (in java)?

Comment: That line *might* create a `String` object.  If `"abc"` is already in the string pool, it'll just point `abc` at the existing object.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by how..a String literal is a String object by definition. See [the Java Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3052442/10077

Comment: imho this question seems primarily about the prescribed operation of the JVM, not the JLS definition of a string literal--I suggest we reopen it

Comment: This is just built into the Java language; it's not something that works for anything other than strings.  It's just how Java works.

Comment: this is not a duplicate question, this question is more about how JVM works