# JAVA : forming a string object

Tags: java, string, oop, object

What is the difference between forming a new object of class `String` by following 2 methods :

1. `String str1 = "Welcome";`
2. `String str1 = new String("Welcome");`

Comment: First one uses a literal object from the constant pool. Which means it will fetch same object every time you refer to `"Welcome"` literal. Second one is creating a new object every time.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more or post some link regarding the same. What is a literal object ?

Comment: Check the page which is provided by Andy, in particular this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23546082/5343269 . A literal in a programming language is a sequence of characters which represent some value but are not stored in any variable. For example, `1234` is an integer literal, `Welcome` is String literal, `True/False` are boolean literals, `1E-20` is a floating point literal.