# Incorrect value returned by IdentityHashMap - Why?

Tags: java, hashmap

To my understanding, the following code should print `false` as it is doing `identity` based comparison.

However, when I run the following code it is printing `true`:

```
public class Test1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    IdentityHashMap m = new IdentityHashMap();
    m.put("A", new String("B"));
    System.out.println(m.remove("A", new String("B")));
  }
}
```

Can some one help me understand why this behaving like this?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext, so I've reopened - it's pretty clear the OP is aware of the difference :)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth *"it's pretty clear the OP is aware of the difference :)"* Yet he acceppted that dupe ;D. (but I agree, it isn't a dupe of that question)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth-- I made a mistake of blindly trusting the MOD'S..:D

Comment: Unrelated again: anybody with a gold java badge can close-as-dup. It is rather rare that moderators do that. Only folks with that red diamond next to the user id are moderators!

Comment: @GhostCat first comment: indeed! it's the third (in a week or two) excellent question that I see from OP.

Comment: @GhostCat Same thing happens to me with Spring specifically, but most of those questions get filed directly on the Spring JIRA. ;-)

Comment: Just noticed I missed to upvote your nice question ;-)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You have actually hit a bug in JDK, see [JDK-8178355](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178355). `IdentityHashMap` does not have custom implementation of the `remove(K,V)` method added to `Map` via default method, which is causing this issue.

Comment: Beyond that; I find it almost funny how the comments in that bug report express what I added to my answer: "when you start doing such things, it is very easy to get it wrong"

Comment: @GhostCat Your analysis is very thorough and spot on.

Comment: :-) You already have my vote, and SO doesn't allow multiple votes , so will  just need wait for others for the thumbs up.

Comment: It is bug ONLY in OpenJDK? OP has written nothing of the Java version he uses.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo That really depends who exactly implements that **library** class. Many of the common classes ... are simply shared here!

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo The bug is there in Oracle JDK as well. Not sure about other proprietory JDK flavours though.

Answer (score 29):

You **put** "A", new "B"

You **remove** "A", new "B"

So, yes, your assumption that this IdentityHashMap should **not** remove that value *looks* correct.

But you are using the `remove(key, value)` method from the **base** AbstractMap - which is **not** overriden by this specific subclass!

So, although the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) says:

> This class implements the Map interface with a hash table, using reference-equality in place of object-equality when comparing keys (and values).

The *(and values)* part is (probably) implemented only for **inserting** key/value pairs.

So, the important part again comes from the javadoc:

> This class is not a general-purpose Map implementation! While this class implements the Map interface, it intentionally violates Map's general contract, which mandates the use of the equals method when comparing objects. This class is designed for use only in the rare cases wherein reference-equality semantics are required.

My (probably opinionated) take-away: this class is a very special thing. It has a very clear, and narrow purpose. And you found an example where it falls apart. (which I don't find surprising: when you "change" semantics but decide to re-use existing code, it is almost inevitable to run into such kind of inconsistencies).

It *could* be seen as bug; and as the other answer confirms: it is a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178355)!

Comment: So in some senses this is an implementation bug - the behaviour doesn't match the Javadoc description of this class.