# Do we create object when we make string without new operator?

Tags: java, string, object

```
class Help {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "hello";
        String s2 = "hello" + "world";
    }
}
```

- Is `s1` here an object reference variable, or did we create an object in the first statement?

  - If answer is yes, then in the second statement how many objects will be created ?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between “text” and new String(“text”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3052442)

Comment: In short since `"hello"` and `"world"` are *compilation time constants* which value is known at compilation time, compiler will do concatenation and compile `"hello"+"world"` as if it was written like `"helloworld"`.

Answer (score 1):

No. You will create a new `String` object always when you use new operator. If you create a `String` normally without new operator it will return an existing object from String pool if it is already existing, if its not it will create a new one

Refer this [example](http://www.java67.com/2014/08/difference-between-string-literal-and-new-String-object-Java.html) for more info