# Java returning false on comparing two equal strings

Tags: java, string

When I execute:

```
String a = "hello";
String b = "hello";
System.out.println(a==b);
```

I get output as "true".

But when I run:

```
String a = new String("hello");
String b = "hello";
System.out.println(a==b);
```

I get output as "false".

I understand that in the first case, Java makes 'b' point to the same object where 'a' pointed, but why can't it do that in the second case?

Comment: Because you are explicitly telling it to create a new object.

Comment: @racraman Yes, but only for 'a'. While creating 'b', Java should search for an object already containing "hello" and that to 'b' - as it did it in the first case.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicated question..

Comment: In short, `==` compares references, `.equals()` compares your String content.

Comment: `Java should search ... as it did it in the first case. ` No, it shouldn't, since that would have a (big) impact on runtime speed.   In the first case, the "search" does NOT happen at runtime but at compile time against compile-time constants, and so there is no impact on runtime speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the following well explained answer on stackoverflow:
[What is the difference between "text" and new String("text")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext)

Answer (score 2):

String in Java are immutable. Meaning:

```
String a = "hello";
String b = "hello";
```

a and b are litterally pointing to the same object in memory

Here you explicitly create a new object

```
String a = new String("hello");
String b = "hello";
```

Hence the 2 are not equal.

`==` compares the memory address. To check if an Object is equal to another in Java you should use the `equals` method that is on all objects.

If you rewrite `System.out.println(a==b);` to `System.out.println(a.equals(b));` it will be true for both cases