# Elegant Solutions to the Fencepost Problem (with Strings)

Tags: java, string-formatting, string-concatenation, fencepost

What I'm referring to is concatenating `String`s with a certain `String` in the middle, such as concatenating sentences separated by a period, or parameter lists with a comma. I know you can use libraries, but sometimes these can't do what you want, like when you want to generate the phrases you are concatenating. So far I've come up with two solutions,

```
StringBuffer sentence = new StringBuffer();
String period = "";
for ( int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++ ) {
    sentence.append( period + sentences[i] );
    period = ". ";
}
```

which suffers from the redundant reassignment of `period`. There is also

```
StringBuffer actualParameters = new StringBuffer();
actualParameters.append( parameters[0] );
for ( int i = 1; i < parameters.length; i++ ) {
    actualParameters.append( ", " + parameters[i] );
}
```

which removes the reassignment but which still looks unappealing. Any other solutions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [family of functions in Apache Commons Lang that does just that](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.String%29).

If you have to code it yourself, the way I usually do this sort of thing is as follows:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String sentence : sentences) {
    if (sb.length() != 0) {
        sb.append(". ");
    }
    sb.append(sentence);
}
```

This version permits `sentences` to be any iterable (returning strings). Also note the use of `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.

It is easy to generalize this to something akin to `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join`.

Comment: This is a nice solution using the extended `for` loop that I hadn't considered, thanks.

Comment: This is a very nice solution, best here so far

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a common question!

[Remove last character of a StringBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395286/java-remove-last-character-of-a-stringbuilder)

That would lead to something like:

```
StringBuffer sentence = new StringBuffer();
String separator = ", ";
for ( int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++ ) {
    sentence.append( sentences[i] )
    sentence.append( separator );
}
sentence.setLength(sentence.length() - separator.length());
```

Comment: +1 Very nice solution taking constant time, thinking outside the box :) (`sb` needs to be replaced with `sentence`, though) And thanks for the link.

Comment: don't use `+` if you are already using a StringBuffer! Use a second `append`! The main reason for using the StringBuffer is to avoid `+` which creates an additional StringBuffer (each interaction).

Comment: this crashes if `sentences` is empty

Answer (score 1):

If you have at least one string then:

```
String join(String separator, String... strings)
{
    String s = strings[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < strings.length; i++) {
        s += separator + strings[i]; 
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: This is actually the same as the second solution I have presented except it is using `String` concatenation to build up the result, although this would not be recommended for the reasons outlined in other comments, in particular that made by Carlos Heuberger.

Comment: Modern Java compilers convert String concatenation to StringBuilder + append() calls. Try using javap -c on the class to see the generated code. Although this isn't always as efficient as hand generated code it can be, but always has the benefit of simpler to follow source code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String join(String sep, String... parts) {
  boolean first = true;
  final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for(String part: parts) {
    if(first)
      first = false;
    else
      sb.append(sep);
    sb.append(part);
  }
}
```

Don't use StringBuffer because of unnecessary synchronisation and "+" operator, because this will create unnecassry intemediate String objects.

Comment: +1 for the information about StringBuffer and "+" operator, -1 for the code. It again suffers from the added complexity of an extra conditional that the other two answers have...