# How to do the opposite of StringBuilder append in Java?

Tags: java

What would be the opposite of:

```
savedPlanets.append(planet.getDisplayName()+",");
```

I have a list and I am adding the name of the planet every time the user clicks on a checkbox, I want to remove the name from the savedPlanets if the checkbox is cleared

Comment: remove.  the beauty is you get to declare what you want it to be.. maybe destroyPlanet() :)

Comment: savedPlanets is a String.

How would I implement a set of data?

Comment: if savedPlanet is a string, just replace it with empty string

Comment: @Randy how could I implement that?

I can't empty the String as I need the other values

Comment: make a new class Planets.  create methods for addPlanet, RemovePlanet.. etc.  also include toString() to get the string you are trying to create here.

Comment: Single character subset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395286/remove-last-character-of-a-stringbuilder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do following:

```
 savedPlanets.replace(planet.getDisplayName(),"");
```

Ideally I would do a solution like following:

```
Set<String> selectedPlanets = new HashSet<String>();

selectedPlanets.add(planet.getDisplayName());        // Whenever a planet is selected
selectedPlanets.remove(planet.getDisplayName());     // Whenever a planet is removed 

// Prepare a String with all planets        
StringBuilder savedPlanets = new StringBuilder("");
for(String planetName : selectedPlanets ){
    savedPlanets.append(planetName).append(",");
}
// Removing , from the end if any       
if(savedPlanets.toString().endsWith(","))
    finalValue = savedPlanets.substring(0, savedPlanets.length()-1);

// finalValue is what you are looking for
```

Comment: nice thought.  but really this wants to be a map or set of some sort.  then the string is a toString function return value.

Comment: Rather than building the string yourself, I would use a String/Collection utility library (Guava's Joiner or Commons StringUtils) which take a similar approach but don't duplicate the String object with use of substring and are flexible in the separator that is used (read: higher reuse)

Answer (score 1):

I would rebuilt the string each time, only including the element you want to include.

e.g.

```
Set<Planet> planets = ...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String sep = "";
for(Planet planet: planets) {
   sb.append(sep).append(planet.getDisplayName());
   sep = ",";
}
String planetNames = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Nice approach. Apache Commons StringUtils is flexible and handles this nicely, as does Guava's Joiner library. I would lean towards using those in a project of any size. For example, StringUtils optimizes the StringBuilder initial size and handles nulls gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using StringBuffer or something like that. It's not a good solution it this case, I would recommend you to use Set. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Implement it like this:

```
Set planets = new HashSet();
planets.add("a");
planets.add("b");
planets.remove("a");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume...
    **StringBuffer savedPlanets...**

**APPEND :** `savedPlanets.append(planet.getDisplayName()+",");`

**OPPOSITE OF APPEND :** `savedPlanets.replaceAll(planet.getDisplayName()+",","");`

**EX:**

```
savedPlanets.append("Earth,");
savedPlanets.append("Mercury,");
savedPlanets.append("Venus,");
```

now **savedPlanetes= "Earth,Mercury,Venus,";**

then

```
savedPlanets.replaceAll("Venus,",""); <-----
```

now value will be **savedPlanetes= "Earth,Mercury,";**