# Java: Remove String from StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I want to remove String from StringBuilder

Example

```
String aaa = "sample";
String bbb = "sample2";
String ccc = "sample3";
```

In another part

```
StringBuilder ddd = new StringBuilder();
ddd.append(aaa);
ddd.append(bbb);
ddd.append(ccc);
```

I want to check if StringBuilder ddd contains String aaa and remove it

```
if (ddd.toString().contains(aaa)) {
    //Remove String aaa from StringBuilder ddd
}
```

Is that possible? Or is there any other way to do like that?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12353395/3227787).

Comment: Why add it in the first place? I'm assuming this is a very contrived sample: why can't you add a check to whatever condition it is before adding `aaa`?

Comment: @devnull. This is not exactly a duplicate, although close.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel. Not necessarily contrived. A StringBuilder can be created from a pre-existing string or other source. Removing bits of it may not be the best way to handle things, as you point out, but it may be the only alternative in some cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this

```
    int i = ddd.indexOf(aaa);
    if (i != -1) {
        ddd.delete(i, i + aaa.length());
    }
```

Comment: You need to do `i + aaa.length()` for the second argument, as [`StringBuilder#delete`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete%28int,%20int%29) takes an `end` index, not a length.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
public void delete(StringBuilder sb, String s) {
    int start = sb.indexOf(s);
    if(start < 0)
        return;

    sb.delete(start, start + s.length());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a string from ddd and use replace().

```
ddd.toString().replace(aaa,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by :

```
ddd.delete(from, to);
```

Comment: And, for performance, use `indexOf` instead of `toString().contains`