# Removing several "\r\n" or "\n" at the end of a StringBuilder in Java

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I need to remove several 'newline' at the end of my StringBuilder.

I tried the following code.

```
while(sb.lastIndexOf("\r\n") == sb.length()){
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
}
```

It's not working. Anyone have any tips ?

Comment: If you are using Java 8, I'd recommend [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html), if not, consider using `String#endsWith`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove String from StringBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408401/java-remove-string-from-stringbuilder) - see the accepted answer to this question to see how you can replace parts of your StringBuilder instance (with an empty string to remove).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the ending `subSequence` equals your desired substring ("\r\n") and reduce the length with `setLength` like

```
while (sb.subSequence(sb.length() - 2, sb.length()).equals("\r\n")) {
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
}
```

You might also consider calling `toString()` and `trim()`

```
String s = sb.toString().trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Output `sb.lastIndexOf("\n\r")` and `sb.length()` and you'll see the difference in char positions. Therefore the while condition doesn't work.

Also remember: `\n\r` could be `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the string from string buffer **sbString.replaceAll("[\n\r]*$", "")** will do the job for you

Comment: Are you talking about Java StringBuilder? I don't see any `replaceAll()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
   StringBuilder check=new StringBuilder("i am here \n\n\n\n");
    System.out.println(check+" "+check.length());
    Boolean checkexist=true;
    while(checkexist){
         if(check.lastIndexOf("\n")==check.length());{
            check.setLength(check.length()-1);
            if(check.lastIndexOf("\n")==-1){
                 System.out.println(check+" "+check.length());
                checkexist=false;
            }                   

         }
```

Output:

i am here

14

i am here  10

It shows the length of the string after removing all \n in the string