# deleteCharAt or setLength, which way is better to remove last char from a StringBuilder/StringBuffer

Tags: java, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

In many cases, we need to delete the last char of a StringBuilder/StringBuffer. For example, given a `int[]{1,2,3}`, to implement a `String toString(int[] a)` method, contacting each elements with a comma separator. The output should be `1,2,3`, no tailing comma.

We can easily write a loop:

```
int[] nums = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    sb.append(nums[i]);
    sb.append(",");
}
//here we need to remove the tailing ','
```

but always we need to remove the tailing `','`. There are two ways to implement it:

```
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
```

and

```
sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
```

Which one is recommended? Why?

NOTE: 
I know what does `Arrays.toString` do. That's just an example to describe my question, maybe not quite proper. 
**This is not a discussion about strings concatenation but the best practices of StringBuffer/StringBuilder.**

Comment: What's wrong with `Arrays.toString(nums)`? and then delete the first and last char. But a good question about general use.

Comment: @tintinmj: Agree with you. I've edited my question.

Comment: I found out a very close question to yours at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37309/perform-instruction-in-loop-every-time-except-the-last-time).

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3395345/1192381) from @jon-skeet gives an excellent alternative to using StringBuilder without removing any tailing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, there is very little in it and is probably dependent on hardware and other factors.

The `setLength()` method simply alters the count and overwrites the unwanted value in the array with a zero byte.

The `deleteCharAt()` performs an array copy internally, before altering the count. That sounds dramatic, but the array being copied is actually zero-length because you're removing the last character.

I would recommend going for `setLength()` as it is shorter to type and I think makes it clearer what you are doing. If performance is an issue and, on measuring, you find this is the bottleneck for you, then perhaps you could consider a different algorithm that doesn't require changing the size (as per JB Nizet's answer).

Comment: *shorter to type* is not an issue if you are using any IDE.

Comment: +1: both have a negligible cost. Use what you find the clearer to you.

Answer (score 2):

How you do it properly is to conditionally prepend the comma:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0)
        sb.append(',');
    sb.append(nums[i]);
}
```

Then you don't need to worry about removing the last character, because it's already correct.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it like this. Instead, I would only add a trailing comma if the element is not the last element of the array. Or I would use Guava's Joiner (or Apache-commons StringUtils), which makes it much clearer:

```
String s = Joiner.on(',').join(nums);
```

NB: I just noticed that Guava's Joiner doesn't deal with primitive arrays. You should get the idea from the above anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is not a discussion about contacting strings but the best practices of StringBuffer/StringBuilder.

Comment: The best practice, to me, is to avoid appending things that you know you'll have to remove after. Maybe you should come up with a use case where it's really necessary. I can't remember having had to do that in years of programming in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you need even greater speed, your use case might allow you to just keep your own variable

```
int activelength;
```

Then you can just do this operation with

```
activelength--;
```

This would be faster than

```
sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
```

which takes extra time clearing out the byte or word for safety.

Of course, the rest of your context will determine if this is a win for you or not, because other operations you may be needing, such as growing the StringBuilder, would take some extra logic to detect and invoke.