# want to solve this simple one in java for each loop

Tags: java

```
 for (float f: values)
    {
        int a=(int) (f*255);
        builder.append(' ')
               .append(a+",");
    }
```

values is array of float type builder is StringBuilder type on every call I have 3 float values in values array I am trying to append 'a' to builder and ',' here what I am getting is like (255,145,234,) but what I want is like this(255,145,234) I want to omit the last comma your Help is quite helpful to me Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove last character of a StringBuilder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395286/remove-last-character-of-a-stringbuilder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String delimiter = "";
for (float f: values)
    {
        builder.append(delimiter)
        delimiter = ", ";
        int a=(int) (f*255);
        builder.append(a);
    }
```

Alternatively, simply chop off the last character from the `StringBuilder` after the loop exits:

```
builder.setLength(builder.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a `count`, and append `","` until `count` is less than length of array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        float[] values = { 255, 145, 234 };
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int count = 0;

        for (float f : values) {
            count++;
            int a = (int) (f * 255);
            builder.append(' ').append(a);
            if (count < values.length) {
                builder.append(",");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
    }
```

**output**

```
 65025, 36975, 59670
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this. But there is no use of StringBuilder here..

```
    ArrayList<String> val = new ArrayList<>();
    for(float f: values){
        val.add((int)(f*255)+"");
    }
    String s = String.join(", ", val);
    System.out.println(s);
```