# Methods to eliminate the last comma from a StringBuilder Object (running in a Loop) in JAVA 7?

Tags: java, json

Current Output looks like : 
{
    "1": "abc",
    "2": "def",
    "3": "ghi",
}

Expected : 
{
   "1": "abc",
   "2": "def",
   "3": "ghi"
} // No last comma

CODE :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
String nextLine = ""; 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("{ \n");
while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(...);
    sb.append(",");
    sb.append("\n");
}
sb.append("}");
```

Comment: how was the output generated?

Comment: @leon : I am appending the comma after each line, so looks like  { "1": "abc", "2": "def", "3": "ghi", } instead I want to ignore the last comma before appending.

Comment: What is the difference between expected and current output?

Comment: Post you code... you will get a much better response rate

Comment: @MadProgrammer : Input is read from a text file using BufferedReader, trying to convert a text to JSON.

Comment: We need the CODE to see what you have done

Comment: *"trying to convert a text to JSON"* - Use a JSON library

Comment: get the length if it is equal to length(last element) not append comma..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove last character of a StringBuilder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395286/remove-last-character-of-a-stringbuilder)

Comment: @MadProgrammer not wanting to use a JSON library as the text file will vary.

Comment: @Ragu how do you do that ?!

Comment: @devk So?  Load the text file and create a JSON array out of the contents like everybody else does

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay, could you brief out ? new to this stuff!

Comment: @devk I did have an example, but the question got closed before I could post it. Take a look at [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) and it's [Encoding examples](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do like -

```
String nextLine = ""; 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("{ \n");
while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(...);
    sb.append(",");
    sb.append("\n");
}

//avoid IndexOutOfBoundsException
int lastIndexOfComma = sb.lastIndexOf(",");
if (lastIndexOfComma != -1)
   sb.deleteCharAt(lastIndexOfComma);
sb.append("}");
```

Comment: This worked for me at the moment! Thanks :) @MrSuS

Comment: Alternatively see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41282608/363573

Answer (score 3):

You can use `deleteCharAt` method

```
StringBuilder strbuilder = new StringBuilder();
strbuilder.append(" { \"1\": \"abc\", \"2\": \"def\", \"3\": \"ghi\",}");

strbuilder.deleteCharAt(strbuilder.length()-(strbuilder.length()-strbuilder.lastIndexOf(",")));
System.out.println(strbuilder.toString());
```

This will give the following output

```
 { "1": "abc", "2": "def", "3": "ghi"}
```

Comment: This works, but building a string just to delete a section later seems very inneficient

Comment: @Leon I agree with your point, this was answered before he post the code. I would chose mbrandeis answer, but that needs a null check and some tweaks

Comment: A solution without `deleteCharAt`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41282608/363573

Answer (score 3):

Ninad's answer is good if you know the length of your input, but in your case you are reading in a loop and may not have that answer beforehand.

In that case, instead of putting a comma after each readline and then handling the odd end-case, you could put the comma before each readline and handle the known start-case.

```
String nextLine = ""; 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("{\n");
nextLine = br.readLine();
sb.append(...);
while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(",\n");
  sb.append(...);
}
sb.append("\n}\n");
```

Comment: What if the first `br.readLine()` returns null?

Answer (score 1):

Please note this is not a best solution , but will work with minimal changes in your code

So to avoid last comma, you can add if condition. When it comes to last index do not add the comma.

Run the loop first to get total count.

```
int lineCount=0;
while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
 lineCount++;
}
```

After that again run the loop (your existing code with if condition)

```
int lineNumber=0;
while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(...);

    if(lineNumber<lineCount){  // if current line is less that total count      
                               // then only attach comma
      sb.append(",");
    }

    sb.append("\n");
    lineNumber++;
}
```

Comment: how does this work? could you please brief?

Comment: In you question - br.readLine()  - what is br ?

Comment: oops, forgot to mention, its an object of BufferedReader -> BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

Answer (score 1):

More Dynamic option

```
       StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("Test,");
       System.out.println("length = " + str.replace(str.length()-1, str.length(), ""));
```

Always good to null check before you do replace.

For your specific case

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("{"1": "abc", "2": "def", "3": "ghi",}");
System.out.println("length = " + str.replace(str.length()-2, str.length()-1, ""));
```