# Java String declaration

Tags: java, string

What is the difference between `String str = new String("SOME")` and `String str="SOME"`
Does these declarations gives performance variation.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334518/java-strings-string-s-new-stringsilly and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390703/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-expression-new-string-in-java

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
String str = new String("SOME")
```

always create a new object on the heap

```
String str="SOME"
```

uses the [String pool](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/ScjpTipLine-StringsLiterally.html)

Try this small example:

```
        String s1 = new String("hello");
        String s2 = "hello";
        String s3 = "hello";

        System.err.println(s1 == s2);
        System.err.println(s2 == s3);
```

To avoid creating unnecesary objects on the heap use the second form.

Comment: The link you shared explains it beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

There is a small difference between both.

Second declaration assignates the reference associated to the constant `SOME`to the variable `str`

First declaration creates a new String having for value the value of the constant `SOME` and assignates its reference to the variable `str`.

In the first case, a second String has been created having the same value that `SOME` which implies more inititialization time. As a consequence, you should avoid it. Furthermore, at compile time, all constants `SOME`are transformed into the same instance, which uses far less memory.

As a consequence, always prefer second syntax.

Comment: For the record, there are scenarios where `new String(String)` makes sense, like if you have a very large string and you're only interested in retaining a small substring. The `substring` methods only return a flyweight view of the original string, so using `new String(hugeString.substring(a, b))` forces a copy and lets the GC reclaim the contents of `hugeString` when it goes out of scope. They shouldn't have made it a constructor, though...

Comment: Interesting case of optimization, indeed, but I wouldn't go this path before having done some profiler checks (so would you, I guess).

Answer (score 1):

```
String s1 = "Welcome"; // Does not create a new instance  
String s2 = new String("Welcome"); // Creates two objects and one reference variable
```

Answer (score 0):

First one will create new String object in heap and str will refer it. In addition literal will also be placed in String pool. It means 2 objects will be created and 1 reference variable.

Second option will create String literal in pool only and str will refer it. So only 1 Object will be created and 1 reference. This option will use the instance from String pool always rather than creating new one each time it is executed.