# why two literals exists in pool with same data

Tags: java, string

```java
public class ConcatenationRuntime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "jim";
        String s3 = "j";
        String im = "im";
        s3=s3+= im;
        System.out.println("s3> " +s3);  // jim
        System.out.println(s1==s3);  // line 8
        System.out.println("Hel" + "lo" == "Hello");  // true
    }
}
```

**Why it is printing false on line 8?** These are all literals, and two references should point to the same literal in the pool - I'm a bit confused.

Comment: How about this for an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8914925/2024761).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why it is returning false at line 8,

Because of `s3=s3+= im;` . 
`Strings` computed by concatenation at runtime are newly created `objects` on heap with there own reference. This `reference` is not same as what reference is provided by `jim` kept in `StringPool` . Hence `s1==s3` is providing false.
But if you intern the String `s3` and then the check for equality it gives true. For example:

`s3.intern() == s1` => returns true

**Why ?** 
Because interning a `String` object first checks if the given string literal exists in `StringPool` or not . If the `String` literal exists in `StringPool` it returns the reference to that String literal , else it stores a copy of that string literal in StringPool and returns the reference to it. Since `jim` is already stored in StringPool , so s3.intern() will simply return the reference to `jim` stored in Stringpool. And hence we get same references. This makes `s3.intern() == s1` to return true.

Comment: thanks for answer, but in that case "Hel" + "lo" is concatenation at runtime(as much as I understand), thus line 9 should also give false

Comment: @Naroji No , it is not concatenation at runtime. While compiling this java file compiler considers it as constant , Since it is the concatenation of two literals not two variables of String