# relationship between pool and heap

Tags: java, string, reflection

See the code.

```
    String xx=new String("hello world");
    String yy="hello world";

    System.out.println("xx: " + xx);
    System.out.println("yy: " + yy);
    System.out.println("xx==yy:"+(xx==yy));  // false

    //modify the value of yy using reflection
    Field yyfield=String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
    yyfield.setAccessible(true);
    char[] value=(char[])yyfield.get(yy);   // change the value of yy
    value[5]='_';

    System.out.println("xx: " + xx);   // xx's value also changed.why?
    System.out.println("yy: " + yy);
    System.out.println("xx==yy:"+(xx==yy));  //false
```

I've seen some posts about [Literal Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914878/how-string-literal-pool-works), know **xx** and **yy** point to different place. But why I change the value of **yy**, **xx** also changed. Is there any operation in reflection or some other aspects I don't know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, they solved.thank you all the same.＠Braj

Comment: Simply always use `equals` for string equality and don't worry about instances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xx` and `yy` are two distinct `String` instances but they refer to the same internal `char[]` array.

This is an implementation-specific detail and changed between the Java versions. In the past, the constructor `String(String)` offered a way to create a `String` with a new `char[]` array for the case that the source `String` is a sub-string of a much larger string. However, current implementations allocate a smaller array and copy contents in the `subString` operation already, eliminating the need for copying in the constructor, hence the constructor `String(String)` simply uses the same array reference.

Even more fancy, the most recent (Java 8) JVMs have a `String` de-duplication feature whereas the garbage collector will change the array references to point to the same array once it found out that two `String` instances have the same contents. So it can collect one of the two arrays while maintaining the same semantics.

Comment: A simple test would be to compare the references of the char array for the 2 Strings :P

Comment: @TheLostMind smart job, i'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

The instance field `value` is the same instance for both `xx` and `yy`. This value  also corresponds to the literal that's interned in the string pool.

Comment: Got it. My understand is : since String is unchangeable , they can share the char[] object?

Comment: @wjk Yes they share the same `char[]` object but this has nothing to do with the `String` class being immutable. This has to do with caching string constants in the JVM.