# Why to create a String object using new

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Strings: “String s = new String(”silly“);”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334518/java-strings-string-s-new-stringsilly)
>   [What is the purpose of the expression “new String(…)” in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390703/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-expression-new-string-in-java)

There are two ways to create a String object:

1) using literal as in String s ="hello" (creates one object)
2) using new as in String s = new String("hello") (creates two objects)

I was wondering why do ever I need to go for 2) approach?

Comment: Interestingly, the .Net team agreed with you: there's no `String` constructor that accepts another `String` object.

Comment: You need to go with approach 2 when you want your String objects to be created in the heap and want them to be garbage collected quickly. When you create String's using literals they are created in PermGen and are Garbage collected only when the class is unloaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic difference between them is memory allocation.

First option i.e

```
String s1 = "hello";
```

When you use this **s1** is called as a **string literal** and memory for s1 is allocated at **compile time**.

But in 2nd case

```
String s2 = new String("hello");
```

In this case s2 is called as an object of String representing **hello**

When you tries to create two string literal using the first case, only one memory is referenced by those two literals. I mean String literals are working with a concept of **string pool**. when you create a 2nd string literal with same content, instead of allocating a new space compiler will return the same reference. Hence you will get **true** when you compare those two literals using **==** operator.

But in the 2nd case each time JVM will create a new object for each. and you have to compare their contents using **equals()** method but not with **==** operator.

If you want to create a new string object using 2nd case and also you don't want a new object, then you can use **intern()** method to get the same object.

```
String s = "hello";
String s1 = new String("hello").intern();
System.out.println(s == s1);
```

In this case instead of creating a new object, JVM will return the same reference **s**. So the output will be **true**

Comment: This is not what is expected of the question. When String pool is more memory efficient, then why do we need to use new keyword and create more memory.?

Answer (score 12):

If you create a string with new, then you get a different String reference. This can avoid creepy behaviour:

```
String s = "hello";
String t = "hello";
String u = new String("hello");
System.out.println(s==t);
System.out.println(t==u);
```

prints true, false. I can't really think of a real bit of software where I'd use this. But in a sense it is 'safer' to create new references, so that == doesn't surprise us.

Comment: Do you use the second approach in your programs?

Comment: Here is a more serious example: suppose you have a `substring` of a really large string.  Doing `new String(hugeString.substring(0, 10))` prevents you from retaining a reference to that huge string and allows it to be garbage collected.  That's a genuinely real-world-appropriate case.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is just a possibility. Actually is never used (by most of developers). The first one is a less and more convenient version of the latter, no reasons to use the second way.

PS. The second just creates a different link to the literal. Technically they will re-use the same char array. The only difference is the reference will be different (i.e. == will give false, but NEVER use == for string comparison).

Comment: But I have read that creating String object using new creates two objects, one object will be created using new and second one using String literal..

Comment: It will create another reference to the string literal. Technically they will re-use the same char array. The only difference is the reference will be different (i.e. == will give false, but NEVER use == for string comparison).

Answer (score 1):

The *only* mentally sane occasion where `new String("foo")` should be used are unit-tests. You can make sure that the code does not use `==` for string comparisons but the proper `.equals()` method.

Comment: What about `Object lock1 = new String ( "Lock" ) ; Object lock2 = new String ( "Lock" ) ; ... synchronized ( lock1 ) { ... }`? Not really a strong case, but I think it is also a sane usage of `new String("foo")`.

Comment: @emory:I don't think so, because `new Object()` does the same job with less noise and without the "why did he use a string for that?` much later.

Answer (score 0):

This can be understood as a constructor per copy. They are very used in C++. The net effect is  having a duplicate of the object passed as a parameter, in this case, a String.

Comment: But contrary to C++ strings in Jvaa are immutable. Hence taking a copy is quite useless.

Comment: Yes, this is very theorical, but in fact rarely used!