# Shouldn't I do `String s = new String("a new string");` in Java, even with automatic string interning?

Tags: java, string, object, string-interning

Ok, this question is an extension of this question

[Java Strings: "String s = new String("silly");"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334518/java-strings-string-s-new-stringsilly)

The above question asked the same question as this one, but I have a new doubting point.

According to `Effective Java` and the answers of above question, we should **not** do `String s = new String("a new string");`, because that will create unnecessary object.

I am not sure about this conclusion, because I think Java is doing [automatic string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), which means for a string, anyway there is only one copy of it in the memory.

So let's see `String s = new String("a new string");`.

`"a new string"` is already a string which has been created in the memory.

When I do `String s = new String("a new string");`, then the `s` is also `"a new string"`. So according to `automatic string interning`, `s` should be pointed to the same memory address of `"a new string"`, right?

Then how can we say we create unnecessary objects?

Comment: There *is* only one copy of the String *unless you do `new String(...)`*. Don't do it unless you have to.

Comment: +1 for interesting question, never thought about it. However, most of the time you can check this stuff by looking into the differences (or lack of differences) in bytecode between the 2 versions.

Comment: `intern`ing is only automatically performed on `String` literals.

Comment: Because there's another string, that's what `new` does.

Comment: What makes you think that `new String("a new string")` is better than `"a new string"`? I can't understand why you want to use the former.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no I am not saying i prefer and I am just wondering whether the statement `we should NOT do that` is true or not. Also, if `new string("a string")` is so bad, why doesn't Java simply remove this constructor?

Comment: You can do it if you want. Nobody dies if you do. You just create extra objects that aren't needed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I disagree. A puppy is killed every time this is done. I know this for a fact.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I guess that is meant to be funny. But really, do you believe that it ever really matters that much? Presumably you have evidence. I mean, I wouldn't use new to create strings but I think it would be hard to come up with a scenario where it actually mattered.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: nah, it doesn't matter that much, unless the code is creating a lot of String objects in a tight loop, and then object creation can be somewhat expensive. It's just a good habit to avoid creating new Strings so as to not run into this problem inadvertently.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
String a = "foo"; // this string will be interned
String b = "foo"; // interned to the same string as a
boolean c = a == b; //this will be true
String d = new String(a); // this creates a new non-interned String
boolean e = a == d; // this will be false
String f = "f";
String g = "oo";
String h = f + g; //this creates a new non-interned string
boolean i = h == a // this will be false
File fi = ...;
BufferedReader br = ...;
String j = br.readLine();
boolean k = a == j; // this will always be false. Data that you've read it is not automatically interned
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read more about **String literal pool** in JVMs. Quick googling pointed me to this article:
http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3
which seems quite valid.

Also you may be interested in Integer literal pooling as well as other literals pooling in Java.

Answer (score 0):

using "=" instead of "=new String" is better since it might result in a single instance instead of multiple instances.