# Reusability of Strings in java?

Tags: java

```
String h = "hi";
```

here we are referencing string h to string literal hi. JVM has a string literal pool  to store string literals so we can reuse the strings as they re immutable...

When we say `reusable,` what is the exact meaning of this? are we talking about the `address` ? that it is picked from same address evey time ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, to make things simpler you can think of it as picking from same address, but to be more precise variables are holding same *reference* which is number/objectID which JVM *use* while mapping to proper memory address of object (object can be moved in memory but will still have same reference).

You can test it with code like this:

```
String w1 = "word";
String w2 = "word";
String b = new String("word"); // explicitly created String (by `new` operator) 
                               // won't be placed in string pool automatically
System.out.println(w1 == w2);  // true  -> variables hold same reference
System.out.println(w1 == b);   // false -> variable hold different references,
                               // so they represent different objects
b = b.intern(); // checks if pool contains this string, if not puts this string in pool, 
                // then returns reference of string from pool and stores it in `b` variable
System.out.println(w1 == b);   // true  -> now b holds same reference as w1
```

Comment: b = b.intern(); // put string into pool of strings, return it from pool, then store it in b refrence.... put it in pool ok rest not understood :(

Comment: I need to store somewhare value from `b.intern()` because String is immutable (can't be changed) so I do `b=b.intern()` thats why i wrote "store it in b refrence"

Comment: I was just reading some stuff.. when u say string cant be changed once it is created, whats does that mean ? [sorry 4 amateur questions]

Comment: No problem [I am amateur 2]. Immutable = there are no methods to change value of object. In String case you can see methods like substring and it could seem that it does something on your String, but in reality it creates new one, then returns it as result. Original String from which you invoked substring method (or any other method) is untouched.

Answer (score 9):

In the case of

```
String h = "hi";
String i = "hi";
String j = new String("hi");
```

Depending on the version of the JDK the compiler **may** do what is called [**interning**](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/01/busting-javalangstringintern-myths.html) and create a single instance of the byte data that represents the `"hi"` and reuse it between the to variable references. In the most recent specifications all [String **literals**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.10.5) are interned into the String pool in the Permanent Generation.

Using the `new` keyword as in the last statement will create a **new instance** of the exact same bytes as a separate object.

String objects created at **runtime** are **not** in the String pool unless `.intern()` is called on them. [This is usually not needed and can cause problems, rarely has any significant benefits.](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/01/busting-javalangstringintern-myths.html)

```
h == i; // true
h == j; // false
j.intern();
h == j; // true
```

Comment: String h = "hi";  and String  i = new String("hi"); .... something different happens in this case ?

Comment: so that the content "hi" of h and i is stored at one address and content "hi" of object j is stored at another address am i correct ?

Answer (score 5):

What is meant is that if 20 objects use the same literal String:

```
private String h = "hi";
```

all these objects will in fact reference the same String instance in memory. And it doesn't matter, because it's impossible to change the content of the String, since it's immutable. The same instance can thus be shared without problems between objects.

Answer (score 4):

There's a `String` literal pool inside the JVM with all the `String`s created during the lifetime of the program. By reusable, it is meant that, when you want to use another `String` with exactly the same characters and encoding, a new `String` object is not created. Instead, the reference will point to the already existing `String` in the string pool. This is called interning.

This can be done because `String`s are immutable in Java.

The reason for doing something like this is to avoid the cost of creating a new `String` object.

Look here for more details about what the String literal pool is and how it works: http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3

Also, look at this question: [Shouldn't I do `String s = new String("a new string");` in Java, even with automatic string interning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666537/shouldnt-i-do-string-s-new-stringa-new-string-in-java-even-with-autom)