# why is this coming out true, shouldn't it be false given its from different locations

Tags: java

```
String x = "Hello!";

String y = "Hello!";

System.out.println( x == y );
```

How come this is still coming out `true`, aren't they referring to different locations in heap memory?

Comment: **aren't they referring to different locations in heap memory?** No they both are compile time constant so the are in the string pool pointing to same memory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What makes reference comparison (==) work for some strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698260/what-makes-reference-comparison-work-for-some-strings-in-java)

Comment: The image in this answer helps you to understand the question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17489410/1927832

Answer (score 2):

The JVM stores String literals in a pool for reuse. more information here: [Reusability of Strings in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759844/reusability-of-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

**NO** . They aren't  referring to different locations. Since its a String literal, It will not create a new object for `y` , rather it will refer to the same object which is already created for `x` in the string pool.

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in [JLS 3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) (and 15.28, which 3.10.5 references):

> A string literal is a reference to an instance of class `String` ([§4.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1), [§4.3.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.3)).
>
> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the *same* instance of class `String`. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions ([§15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method `String.intern`.