# How does the JVM reuse interned String substrings?

Tags: java, string, specifications, effective-java

I'm aware if you make

```
for (condition) {
    String s = "hi there";
}
```

Just one `String` instance is created in all the iterations, unlike `String s = new String("hi there");` that will create a new instance in each iteration.

But, reading Effective Java from Joshua Bloch: Chapter 2 Item 5 (page 20) it states:

> Furthermore, it is guaranteed that the object will be
>   reused by any other code running in the same virtual machine that happens to **contain** the same string literal [[JLS, 3.10.5]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5).

AFAIK that does not say *happens to **be** the same string literal*, it says **contains**.

Reading [[JLS, 3.10.5]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) cannot find any exact reference to this and I have a doubt.

Giving this snippet:

```
String s1 = "hi ";
String s2 = "there";
String s3 = "hi there";
```

How many instances are created?

- 3 instances (thus, phrase is not really exact).
- 2 instances, `s1` and `s2` (then `s3` is created reusing `s1` and `s2` references)

Comment: He probably means "the virtual machine contains ..", not the string contains another string

Comment: I am not sure, so a comment instead of an answer. But I think that the "contain" is partially wrong and your example indeed yields three instances.

Comment: @glglgl actually is what *my logic* says, but can be JVM smart enough to create `s3` as a reference to `s1` + `s2`??

Comment: It reuses object from String pool. So yes there will be three instances since each of them are (at that point) three different immutable objects. The word I was killing myself to use was "Intern" which is what JVM does. I suppose if you are asking whether JVM "Cleverly substrings" String objects to optimise RT memory usage - not too sure if it does. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759844/reusability-of-strings-in-java) might help?

Comment: @glglgl The use of contain is not wrong, the OP is just reading the word contain wrong, and missing the fact it is talking about other code that contain the **same string literal**. A substring is not a string literal, the text is also not talking about string literals containing other string literals.

Comment: @ha9u63ar AFAIK the string type no longer supports shared substring storage since Java 7.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The JLS does not guarantee any reuse of sub-strings whatsoever. The "contain" here is just meant that the *class* mentions the exact same string literal somewhere. It is *not* used in the "substring of" sense.

Comment: Specifically _"any other code [..] that happens to contain the **same string literal**"_ (emphasis mine)

Comment: when you say *not guarantee any reuse of sub-strings* means it can happen sometimes?

Comment: @JordiCastilla: I don't think any current VM reuses substrings, but it is possible (and previous iterations of OpenJDK for example did sometimes  share the underlying char[] when two strings were substrings of each other). Note that you'd *still* observe separate `String` instances and there's no public API to detect if that's happening (i.e. you wouldn't be able to tell without some reflection trickery).

Comment: @JoachimSauer "when two strings were substrings of each other" - as far as I can reason, the only case in which to sets would be mutual subsets of each other would be when they are identical, no?!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: sure, should have phrased it differently: "when there are two strings where one is a substring of the other".

Comment: @JordiCastilla a bit late, but yes, “it can happen sometimes” in practice where “sometimes” means “when the resulting string has zero length”.

Answer (score 3):

Each class file contains a list of all the string literals or other constants used within that class (except for small numeric constants which are embedded within the instruction stream).  If the item 19 in the list is the string literal `"Freddy"`, and local variable `Fred` has an index of 6, then the bytecode generated for `Fred="Freddy";` would likely be `ldc 19`/`astore 6`.

When a class is loaded, the system will build a table of all the constants and--for those of reference type--the objects identified thereby.  If no instance of a string literal is known to exist, the system will add one to the interning table and store a reference to that.  When generating machine code, the `ldc 19` will then be replaced with an instruction to load the appropriate reference.

What's important is that by the time any of the code in a class runs, objects have been created for all the string literals therein, so a statement like `Fred="Freddy";` will merely store a reference to an already-existing `String` object containing `Freddy`, rather than creating a new `String` object.

Answer (score 2):

If `s3` reused `s1` and `s2` instances, then `s3` would not be physically represented as a continuous character array, but would rather be a composite `String` of `String`s objects.

Now imagine the performance impact to accessing individual characters within such a string - index based access would actually involve comparing the index value with the size of the first string, then calculation of offset which would become index for the second string, etc.

Actually, the opposite could make sense: Only one underlying char sequence could be allocated for `"hi there"` (`s3`), and `s1` and `s2` could just store their lengths and addresses of the first character within that string. But I assume that it would be a complex and expensive work for jvm to identify the 'embeddable' candidates and that the cost would outweigh the potential benefit.

Comment: Well, prior to Java 7 the `substring`-method used to be implemented in a way that it returned a String backed by the original String's character array, but even that was dropped because it caused more harm than good (large texts could be kept alive by holding a reference to some tiny substring, for example)

Comment: @Hulk: It has been [change in Java7update6](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4513622). It’s not only a gc issue; it requires every string to carry an `offset` and `length` field for the sole purpose of a single operation, `substring`. Further, the string deduplication feature of recent JVMs benefits from the simplified object layout as a single `cas` on the `value` field is sufficient.