# Why this java code gives different answers?

Tags: java, string

Why the following java code gives answer as:

not equal
equal.

Code:

```
    String a=new String("abc");
    String b=new String("abc");
    String c="abc";
    String d="abc";


    if(a==b){
        System.out.println("equal");
    }else{
        System.out.println("not equal");
    }

    if(c==d){
        System.out.println("equal");
    }else{
        System.out.println("not equal");
    }
```

I am confused as to what is the way the two statements

```
        String a=new String("abc");
        String c="abc";
```

differ in ?
In simple words what is the difference between the two assignments ?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This has been asked **many** times before. Here is one explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/334613/367273

Comment: You should look at [String.intern()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) and research it carefully. `All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a string literal to *directly* initialize a string variable, Java will [intern the Java literal string](http://javatechniques.com/blog/string-equality-and-interning/), so that both string variables refer to the same actual string object.

When you use the `new` operator, you get a different object, even if the contents of the new string is the same as the string literal.

And as has been pointed out many times, the `==` operator compares object references to see if they point to the same object, and does not compare string contents.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `==` to compare strings; use `equals()` method.

```
if(a.equals(b)) {
    System.out.println("equal");
}else{
    System.out.println("not equal");
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer why they are equal the second time.

Comment: Yes, it does.  They are the same reference, so == returns true.

Comment: Does not really answer the question but is a good advice :)

Comment: It's not obvious that they are the same reference. Especially to a new programmer.

Comment: It's obvious to anyone who's read how the equals method and the == operator work.  And I'd argue that you shouldn't be programming or asking questions here if you haven't read the material.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a string literal will utilize the string pool (hence the equal reference), `new`ing a String will always create a new instance which results in different objects.