# difference between two java String assignment types

Tags: java

what is the difference between these two implementations :

```
String s1 = "java";
```

and

```
String s2 = new String("java");
```

is s1 is able to perform all the functions that s2 will do?? like to uppercase, append etc..

Comment: Yes, they will perform all the same functions.

Comment: Also related: [Java Strings: “String s = new String(”silly“);”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334518/java-strings-string-s-new-stringsilly)

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext-in-java

Answer (score 1):

The only Difference is `String s1 = "java"` will create a String Literal and it will be stored in a String Pool And for `String s2 = new Sting("java")` an Instance object will be created plus a String Literal in String pool.

For Second part `Yes` you can, Since its a Variable and variable can access library function using dot operator. so `s1.toUpperCase()` and `s2.toUpperCase()`.

Ex.

```
class Ideone
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String s1 = new String("java");
    System.out.println(s1.toUpperCase());

    String s2 = "java";
    System.out.println(s2.toUpperCase());
}
 }
```

Result : `JAVA` `JAVA`

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of question, it has been asked many times and answered many times like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext-in-java) and I don't think we need a better answer there

For the second part of your question,

> is s1 is able to perform all the functions that s2 will do?? like to
>   uppercase, append etc..

Absolutely yes! Try `"hello".toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 0):

**String s = "abc";** // creates one String object and one reference variable
In this simple case, "abc" will go in the pool and s will refer to it.

**String s = new String("abc");** // creates two objects and one reference variable
In this case, because we used the new keyword, Java will create a new String object
in normal (nonpool) memory, and s will refer to it. In addition, the literal "abc" will
be placed in the poo

Comment: Nothing will be "placed in the pool" by that line because it's already in the pool.

Comment: So, please can you tell me the exact difference between these two lines, so i can clear my doubt.

Comment: Read my other contributions on this page.

Comment: Thanks, I read this difference from SCJP Sun Certified Programmer for Java book, May be they had given incorrect description.

Comment: SCJP is not a very reliable source of information. It is both outdated and self-serving, targeted at the silly exam instead of real-life code.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1="java"   // will store in string pool
String s2=new String("java");  //will store in heap
```

so  `s1==s2` results in `false`.

if You want s2 also in pool then u have to call `s2.intern()`. After that `s1==s2` results in `true`.