# Confusion about new String and String literals in Java

Tags: java, string

According to Kathy Sierra's book:

```
String s = "abc"; // creates one String object and one
// reference variable
```

In this simple case, `"abc"` will go in the pool and `s` will refer to it.

```
String s = new String("abc"); // creates two objects,
// and one reference variable
```

In this case, because we used the new keyword, Java will create a new String object in normal (nonpool) memory, and `s` will refer to it. In addition,the literal "abc" will be placed in the pool.

---

As I know, when we use literals, it stores value in pool but when we use new keyword it creates object in heap. Here I want to know, is the heap object refer pool data (String) or not?

Comment: This topic has been beaten to death -- there are easily 20 dupes if someone has the energy to search.

Comment: @HotLicks 20 dupes that were closed as dupes of ~10000000 topics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Strings: "String s = new String("silly");"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334518/java-strings-string-s-new-stringsilly)

Comment: It depends on which version of Java you have.  Before around Java 7 update 25, the heap object would have pointed, internally, at the pool (interned) object.  After about update 25, this was changed so that `new String` always copied data into its own buffer, so there was never a reference to another object internally.

Comment: @markspace - An interned String is still in the heap, it's just a permanent resident of the heap.  What may have changed in 7 is that they finally gave up "sharing" the `char[]` array between the interned String and any `new` copies made of that String.

Comment: With JDK 1.8.25 this question becomes interesting again. Because of the String deduplication the string copy will be removed soon. Its a pity that this does not work for SO questions yet...

Answer (score -1):

The variable you created using new String("abc") is not the same as the pool "abc" string.

```
String string1 = "abc";
String string2 = new String("abc");
System.out.println(string1.equals(string2)); //will print true
System.out.println(string1 == string2); //will print false
```