# What is the difference between implicit and explicit String declaration in java?

Tags: java, string, heap-memory, implicit, explicit

For Example..

> String herName = new String("clark");
>
> and
>
> String hisName = "michal";
>
> 1) The first piece of code exactly does,  it will create new string
>   object in the heap memory with reference .
>
> 2) The second line of code ,  its an string literal which create
>   string object in string constant pool, not in actually heap memory.

**`Then what's the benefit, ?`**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334518/java-strings-string-s-new-stringsilly

Answer (score 0):

The *benefit* is that `new String(String s)` is a copy constructor for Strings and works as intended, providing a copy of a given String.

Calling `new String("literally")` is not some special feature designed for literals. In fact, the inverse situation would be most unusual, what good would it be if `new String(String s)` did not work as intended when a literal was used?

Finally, the notion that new object is completely on the heap may be misleading, you do have a new object but because String is immutable it is safely backed by the same `char[] value`, even in the Java 8 source the reference is merely passed on:

```
public String(String original) {
    this.value = original.value;
    this.hash = original.hash;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The second case is susceptible to something called *interning* - if another string is initialized to that same value, the same object will be used for that.

Comment: It's not 'susceptible', it will always be interned.

Comment: ok, it is *highly* susceptible