# How to insert quotes inside parenthesis using a regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string of SVG markup that contains multiples of these:

```
url(#586-xr___83_193_101__rgba_243_156_18_1__0-rgba_243_156_18_1__100)
```

and I need them to be like this:

```
url('#586-xr___83_193_101__rgba_243_156_18_1__0-rgba_243_156_18_1__100')
```

with quotes inside the parenthesis.

These will be mixed inside a long string containing lots of different markup, so needs to be very accurate.

Comment: Edit your question in stead of leaving comment

Comment: There's an "edit" link under your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\((.*?)\)
```

With the replacement string `('$1')`

The idea is capture everything within parentheses and concatenates the `'`

So, you can use a code like this:

```
String str = "url(#586-xr___83_193_101__rgba_243_156_18_1__0-rgba_243_156_18_1__100)";
str = str.replaceAll("\\((.*?)\\)", "('$1')");

//Outuput: url('#586-xr___83_193_101__rgba_243_156_18_1__0-rgba_243_156_18_1__100')
```

**[IdeOne example](https://ideone.com/X5eS3m)**

In case you want a better performance regex you can use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\(([^)]*)\\)", "('$1')");
```

Comment: @frederico  Thanks for the reply...it needs to only do it for parentheses that have url in front of them,  So only hit url()  and NOT rgb()

Comment: @DavidJohnson I don't see other parentheses in your example. Anyway, saw you accepted the answer. Hope to help

Comment: I did say 'These will be mixed inside a long string containing lots of different markup, so needs to be very accurate.'  So inside this markup is other parentheses

Comment: @DavidJohnson sorry, I see... in that case you can use this line: `str = str.replaceAll("\\((.*)\\)", "('$1')");` to make the regex greedy. Bear in mind that this regex will treat `url` as the biggest node. If that doesn't work for you, then you can't use regex.

Comment: str.replaceAll("\\((.*)\\)", "('$1')")  only gets the first and last parentheses in the whole string

Comment: @DavidJohnson then you can't use regex for what you want to do

Comment: this worked in the end: str.replaceAll("url\\('(.*?)'\\)", "url($1)") , I just added the 'url' bit...so your answer was correct apart from that...cheers

Comment: @DavidJohnson great, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

`ReplaceAll` remove a part of the string and put an unrelated and invariant new stuff instead.

Because the replacement string can't be the same at both side, the only solution I imagine (with the constraint of using RegEx and `ReplaceAll`) is to do it in two time:

```
String Str = "url(#586-xr___83_193_101__rgba_243_156_18_1__0-rgba_243_156_18_1__100)";
Str = Str.replaceAll("\\(", "('"); // replace left parenthesis
Str = Str.replaceAll("\\)", "')"); // replace right parenthesis

System.out.print("Return Value: " + Str);
// Return Value: url('#586-xr___83_193_101__rgba_243_156_18_1__0-rgba_243_156_18_1__100')
```

You can test it [here](https://ideone.com/FzLdZ3).

Comment: `new String("")` is [a code smell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334518/java-strings-string-s-new-stringsilly).

Comment: @nickb, I fixed it. My java is a little bit rusted.

Comment: okay thanks for the reply...you don't have to use regex and replaceAll, if there is a better way?