# Difference between creating object with new and assiging value

Tags: java

Can someone tell me the difference between creating object like

```
String s1 = new String("Java");
```

And

```
String S1 = "Java";
```

how it works internally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Strings: "String s = new String("silly");"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334518/java-strings-string-s-new-stringsilly)

Comment: Possible Duplicate  of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334518/java-strings-string-s-new-stringsilly

Comment: If you want to know what `new String(String)` does I suggest you read the source for that constructor.

Comment: One is a terrible idea that should never appear in real code.  The other is not.