# How does String object get formed without use of Constructor?

Tags: java, string, constructor, string-pool

> String s = "abc";

This statement creates one String object. But how? Isn't object creation linked to Constructor? How is an object being created here without use of Constructor?

Comment: @Sam Yes, a bit similar. But there also, there is no answer of "how"? Also, what about the Constructor part? Isn't Constructor supposed to be used in some way to create object? Is a constructor being invoked internally somehow in this case?

Comment: You can also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334518/java-strings-string-s-new-stringsilly

Comment: Ahh, nowhere I can find a simple answer. How? And what about constructor?